# CouchDB slow performance in Docker with "host" network vs. "bridge

Tags: docker, couchdb

I noticed the dockerd and docker-proxy processes were using more CPU than expected, 15% and 24% respectively, so I decided to use the "host" network to avoid the overhead. However, the results I got were much worse. How to explain this?

The same does not happen with a nginx container (performance increases from 43k req/sec to 48k req/sec with "host" network).

## Scenario #1 - "bridge" network

Start CouchDB container: `docker run -d -p 5984:5984 couchdb`

```
$ wrk -d 60 http://localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc
Running 1m test @ http://localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc
  2 threads and 10 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.51ms  197.54us   7.81ms   75.74%
    Req/Sec     3.32k   111.59     3.60k    71.58%
  396492 requests in 1.00m, 698.02MB read
Requests/sec:   6608.12
Transfer/sec:     11.63MB
```

## Scenario #2 - "host" network

Start CouchDB container: `docker run --net=host -d -p 5984:5984 couchdb`

```
$ wrk -d 60 http://localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc
Running 1m test @ http://localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc
  2 threads and 10 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    42.98ms    1.17ms  54.99ms   96.96%
    Req/Sec   116.79     13.73   151.00     56.00%
  13966 requests in 1.00m, 24.59MB read
Requests/sec:    232.57
Transfer/sec:    419.29KB
```

## Environment

- Hardware: i7-6700K, 16GB, SSD
- OS: Fedora 25 (kernel 4.10.13)
- Database: CouchDB 1.6.1